# Do you want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**EDIT:** Please provide feedback on the [Winter Bash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) over on Meta Stack Overflow:

- [What do you think of Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash)

---

If you participated in [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), you may have noticed the [Holiday 2011 Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) last year. It was an event where users could earn "hats" for their gravatars by completing various tasks. It's a somewhat specialized form of a badge in that triggering certain actions would unlock a hat.

[image: hats]

Stack Exchange is running the [promotion](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) again, but this time extending the event to all sites. However, we as a site have to **opt-in** in order to participate. This is completely optional, and there is no obligation to partake in this event at all. If we do choose to participate **individual users can choose to opt-out** via an "I hate hats" option that will be available.

This is something that we can use to engage the community and also drive some activity. It's been too quiet here lately.

If you feel like this is a good idea, please voice your opinion. A response for the site will have to be in by **November 28, 2012** if we want to participate. No response automatically means that we will opt-out of the event.

Comment: I vote yes (but I can't upvote myself).

Comment: There haven't been any negative responses so far, and this looks like as many votes as we'll get. I'll send in the response to **opt-in** tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sent in the response to the Stack Exchange team that **we opt in** for hats. :)

Answer (score 0):

I vote yes!  Let's have some hats!